# GeoServer data directory not writeable

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

I am upgrade GeoServer to 2.20 version, but when specifying the data directory I get the error `Found Java environment variable GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR set to /var/lib/geoserver_data/ , which is not writeable`. I am check the owner of directory geoserver_data and is Tomcat. I am using Tomcat9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer Tomcat 9 versions are more "secure" than previous versions and control where tomcat can read and write outside `$CATALINA_HOME`. You need to find the file `/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service` or equivalent which has the lines:

```
ReadWritePaths=/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/
ReadWritePaths=/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/
```

and add a new line with your data directory.

Then run `systemctl daemon-reload`.